# Проблемы с BoxCollider'ами

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть метод OnTriggerEnter2D(в нём к булевой переменной присваивается значение true) и OnTriggerExit2D(в нём присваивается к булевой переменной false). Проблема заключается в том, что когда я частично задеваю один объект другим, то эта булевая переменная принимает состояние true, но если я полностью наложу один объект на другой эта булевая переменная примет значение false, хотя должна остаться true. Все boxcollider'ы настроены верно и у обоих включено значение isTrigger.

```
 #region BoolPerements
public bool isMouseDown = false;
public bool isTrigger = false;
public bool active = true;
#endregion

#region GameObject
public GameObject keepObject; //Объект, который держим в руке.
public GameObject capObject; //Объект, крышки сокета.
public GameObject openCapLegObject; //Ножка для открытия сокета.
public GameObject intersectedObject; // Пересекаемый объект.
#endregion

#region TransferPerements

[Header("Объект, точки от которой можно передвигать вещи")]
public Transform CenterPoint;
[Header("Максимальная дистанция переноса предметов")]
public float maxDistance = 25;

[Header("Стартовая точка")]
Vector3 StartPosition;

#endregion


void Start()
{
    StartPosition = GetComponent<Transform>().position;

    //Получаем оъекты по тегу
    capObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CpuPlate");
    openCapLegObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("OpenCpu");

    //Присваиваем слои
    capObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().sortingLayerID = SortingLayer.NameToID("Default");

}

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    keepObject = this.gameObject; // Получаем объект, который держим.
    isMouseDown = true;
}

private void OnMouseUp()
{
    isMouseDown = false;
}


private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
{
    if(coll.gameObject.tag == "CPUSoket")
    {
        intersectedObject = coll.gameObject;
        isTrigger = true;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D coll)
{
    isTrigger = false;
}


void Update()
{
    Vector2 cursor = Input.mousePosition;
    cursor = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(cursor);
    float dist = Vector2.Distance(CenterPoint.position, this.transform.position);

    if (active)
    {
        if (isMouseDown)
        {
            if (maxDistance > dist)
                this.transform.position = cursor;
        }
        else
        {
            this.transform.position = StartPosition;
        }

        if (!isMouseDown && isTrigger && keepObject.gameObject.tag == "CPU")
        {
            this.transform.position = intersectedObject.transform.position;
            capObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().sortingLayerID = SortingLayer.NameToID("CpuCup");
            active = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ты делаешь проверку coll.gameObject.tag == "CPUSoket" что бы активировать isTrigger, но при этом любой другой объект может этот тригер выключить. Я не говорю что ошибка тут, но это уже подозрительно

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Именно в этом проблема и была.